# Jquery validation issue on dynamically added input

Tags: jquery

I have created a form and added add more fields using jquery. That is working, the issue is, I have added validation using jquery validation plugin. Validation is working only for first field only. How Can I solve this problem.
I have attached the code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; 
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); 
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); 
    var fieldHTML = '<div class="add_more"><input type="text" name="fname[]" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field">Remove</a></div>'; 
    var x = 1; 
    $(addButton).click(function(){ 
        if(x < maxField){ 
            x++; 
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); 
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('.add_more').remove(); 
        x--; 
    });

        $("#popup").validate({
            rules: {
                "fname[]":"required"
            },
            messages:{
                "fname[]":"First Name required"
            }
        });

});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
input[type="text"]{height:20px; vertical-align:top;}
.field_wrapper div{ margin-bottom:10px;}
.add_button{ margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;vertical-align: text-bottom;}
.remove_button{ margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;vertical-align: text-bottom;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form  action="" method="post" id="popup">
<div class="field_wrapper">
    <div class="add_more">
        <input type="text" name="fname[]" /><br><input type="text" name="fname[]" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">Add More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can try to .clone() or .copy() the input element.

Comment: Clone is working problem with validation. Validate only one field. I want to validate all input field with same name.

Comment: Another option is to create array with "added" elements, then you can iterate it and make validations on submit for example.